# How to add GIN index using Knex.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have been trying to add a GIN index using Knex.js on one of the column in my table, but I can not achieve this. I am trying to do something like this-

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('prediction_models', function(table){
            table.increments('id');
            table.string('model_name').index();
            table.jsonb('model_params');
            table.timestamp('createdAt').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
        })
        .then(createGinIndex());

    function createGinIndex() {
        return knex.raw('CREATE INDEX modelgin ON public.prediction_models USING GIN (model_params);');
    }
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema.dropTable('prediction_models');
};
```

I am using PostgreSQL database. Can anyone please tell me if this is the correct way to implement this? If yes what's wrong with my code and if not how to implement it? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Those looking for a more "knexy" solution to this problem: it's not necessary to use `.raw`, as in Mikael Lepistö's solution. The `.index` chainable accepts a 2nd parameter called `indexType`. It can be used like so:

```
knex.schema.createTable('table_name', table => {
  table.jsonb('column_name').index(null, 'GIN')
})
```

(the `null` on the first parameter is me saying "name this index for me")

This piece of code will produce the following queries:

```
create table "table_name" ("column_name" jsonb);
create index "table_name_column_name_index" on "table_name" using GIN ("column_name")
```

Currently I'm creating such an index but, for performance reasons, I want it to only support the `jsonb_path_ops` operator class (as per [section 8.14.4 of the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html)). This requires a `create index` statement ending in `using GIN ("column_name" jsonb_path_ops)`. As such, I'll need to use a raw but there are plenty of use-cases where `.index` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create full GIN index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX on prediction_models USING GIN (model_params)
```

More info about creating indexes for jsonb columns can be found from end of https://www.vincit.fi/en/blog/objection-js-postgresql-power-json-queries/

You can print out the queries ran by migration like this (http://runkit.com/embed/8fm3z9xzjz9b):

```
var knex = require("knex")({ client: 'pg' });
const queries = knex.schema.createTable('prediction_models', function (table){
    table.increments('id');
    table.string('model_name').index();
    table.jsonb('model_params');
    table.timestamp('createdAt').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
}).raw('CREATE INDEX on prediction_models USING GIN (model_params)')
.toSQL();

queries.forEach(toSql => console.log(toSql.sql));
```

And copy-paste them to psql:

```
mikaelle=# begin;
BEGIN
mikaelle=# create table "prediction_models" ("id" serial primary key, "model_name" varchar(255), "model_params" jsonb, "createdAt" timestamptz default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
CREATE TABLE
mikaelle=# create index "prediction_models_model_name_index" on "prediction_models" ("model_name");
CREATE INDEX
mikaelle=# CREATE INDEX on prediction_models USING GIN (model_params);
CREATE INDEX
mikaelle=# commit;
COMMIT
mikaelle=#
mikaelle=# \d prediction_models
                                     Table "public.prediction_models"
    Column    |           Type           |                           Modifiers                            
--------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 id           | integer                  | not null default nextval('prediction_models_id_seq'::regclass)
 model_name   | character varying(255)   | 
 model_params | jsonb                    | 
 createdAt    | timestamp with time zone | default now()
Indexes:
    "prediction_models_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "prediction_models_model_name_index" btree (model_name)
    "prediction_models_model_params_idx" gin (model_params)

mikaelle=#
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I am using the same query as you suggested but for some reason, I was not able to create an index in the same migration in which I was trying to create a table (note: I was trying to create an index after table creation).  So I created two separate migrations (create table, create index) which worked fine

Comment: @HarshalGangurde that is really strange... I did rendered the queries with https://runkit.com/embed/8fm3z9xzjz9b and did run them in psql inside a transaction, like knex runs them and everything worked fine. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.up = function (knex) {
    const raw = `
    CREATE EXTENSION btree_gin;
    ALTER TABLE employee
    ADD COLUMN employee_index tsvector; 
    UPDATE employee
    SET employee_index = to_tsvector(firstname || ' ' || lastname);
    CREATE INDEX employee_index_gin
    ON employee
    USING GIN (employee_index);
    `

    return knex.schema.raw(raw)
};

exports.down = function (knex) {
    const raw = `
    DROP INDEX employee_index_gin;
    ALTER TABLE employee
    DROP COLUMN employee_index;
    DROP EXTENSION btree_gin;
    `

    return knex.schema.raw(raw)
};
```

used raw for this in my usecase

Answer (score 0):

GIN Indexing cannot be applied to string data types but it is applied to arrays and JSON data types.

```
return knex.schema.table('test_table',(table)=>{
  table.index(['column_name'], 'idx_index_name','GIN');
});
```

If we want to apply built-in operator classes like array_ops, jsonb_ops, jsonb_path_ops, etc. We can index like below example:

```
return knex.schema.table('test_table',(table)=>{
  table.index([knex.raw(`(column_name) jsonb_path_ops`)], 'idx_index_name','GIN')
})
```

Suppose, table users contain address column that is in jsonb and we want to index address.permanent_address, then we can achieve the indexing by following:

```
return knex.schema.table('users',(table)=>{
  table.index([knex.raw(`(address->'permanent_address') jsonb_path_ops`)], 'idx_index_name','GIN')
})
```